# How can I fit one complex object into the bounds of another (simple) one

Tags: modeling

For example if I would like to reproduce a chick growing in an egg. I create the skeleton, the egg, but how can I fit the skeleton into the egg. The morphing from one shape to another might be an option but seems more like a hack. I assume a lot of people need this in character modelling and maybe there is a standard way (modifier) to achieve this. Also if there is a tutorial for something similar it would be great to know.

Comment: shape keys?, or you could get a seperate model and then botch the animation to a multiple layer and just hide a part of it.

Comment: Maybe you could try Cast modifier?
https://youtu.be/PWxN5mP310E?t=432

Comment: Awesome thanks. Did not know about cast modifier. I think that's it.